# How to determine whether a DMARC record exists, or not?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, email, mail-server

A quick search at `mxtoolbox.com` shows:

```
Category    Host    Result  
dmarc   example.com     No DMARC Record found    More Info
spf     example.com     No SPF Record found      More Info
mx      example.com     No DMARC Record found    More Info
mx      example.com     DMARC Quarantine/Reject policy not enabled   More Info
dns     example.com     SOA Expire Value out of recommended range    More Info
```

for a particular domain (not "example.com" obviously).

I was seeing that to lookup `DMARC` records, for example, with dig the syntax is like:

```
dig TXT  _dmarc.example.com
```

But how is the existence of a `DMARC` record established from `dig`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According this support topic [How to Use dig/nslookup to Find SPF, DKIM and DMARC Records for a Domain?](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/secure-email-gateway/217073-how-to-use-dig-nslookup-to-find-spf-dki.html) from CISCO, the syntax to use `dig` to look up DMARC status is:

```
dig _dmarc.domain txt
```

Substitute `domain` with the domain you want to look up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a quick note to the comment above with the dig command.  When the response in the command line comes back, if there is a `dmarc` entry, you'll see it like this:

ANSWER SECTION:

```
_dmarc.gmail.com.   600 IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none; sp=quarantine; rua=mailto:mailauth-reports@google.com"
```

Otherwise, you will get `ANSWER: 0` as the response if there is no `dmarc`.  Hope this helps further!