# How to Use dig to Find DMARC Records for a Domain?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, dns, email

Given [this](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/secure-email-gateway/217073-how-to-use-dig-nslookup-to-find-spf-dki.html) query:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ dig  TXT  _dmarc.cisco.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.8-Ubuntu <<>> TXT _dmarc.cisco.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 3976
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_dmarc.cisco.com.      IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_dmarc.cisco.com.   1238    IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; pct=0; fo=1; ri=3600; rua=mailto:cisco@rua.agari.com,mailto:ynldvgsr@ag.dmarcian.com; ruf=mailto:cisco@ruf.agari.com,mailto:ynldvgsr@fr.dmarcian.com;"

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 10 19:21:51 PDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 231

nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ uname -a
Linux mordor 5.11.0-34-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 19:22:09 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

How is it known whether the `DMARC` record exists or not for Cisco?

Even better, what would be a counter-example where there's [not](https://askubuntu.com/a/1362684/847449) a `DMARC` record?  How would such a query result differ?

If the `Answer` section lacks such an entry as:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
_dmarc.cisco.com.   1238    IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; pct=0; fo=1; ri=3600; rua=mailto:cisco@rua.agari.com,mailto:ynldvgsr@ag.dmarcian.com; ruf=mailto:cisco@ruf.agari.com,mailto:ynldvgsr@fr.dmarcian.com;"
```

then there's a missing `DMARC` record?

Comment: The result is easier to see if you use the `+short` option; that just gives the answer, without any of the surrounding guff. If you want *just a little* verbosity, try e.g. `host -t TXT _dmarc.cisco.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct,

if the answer section is missing, there is no record on that subdomain/DNS entry you are looking up, e.g `_dmarc.domain.com`

If I were to do checks for myself, I would probably just check if the command outputs `v=DMARC1`, like: `dig TXT _dmarc.domain.com | grep v=DMARC1`

However, this does not mean that the DMARC is *valid*. Dig does not check this in itself, so further processing of the output is required, for example regex, or online tools providing validation services such as mxtoolbox.

Comment: Would be interested in further details towards understanding what online services are doing these checks and how they're checking.  I just use `mxtoolbox` for this magic.